# Why after clicking on UITextField all the text in it is cleared?Can I fix this in some way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextField` and when I type some text in it and then select next `UITextField` and then again click on previous all the text in is been erased.Is it possible to save the text when I click on UITextField?

Comment: post code of textBeginEditing

Comment: did you wrote textfield.text=nil; any where in textFielDidBeginEditing delegate,or it is better to show your code,it won't happen if you stay in sameViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You just need to set the `UITextField`'s `clearsOnBeginEditing` to `NO`. Either in code or in IB. In IB there is a checkbox somewhere in the TextField's attributes. Or you just do:

```
self.textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[textField setClearsOnBeginEditing:FALSE];
```

Comment: This should be: `[testField setClearsOnBeginEditing:FALSE];` or `testField.clearsOnBeginEditing = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` has a property for `clearsOnBeginEditing`.

> If this property is set to YES, the text field’s previous text is cleared when the user selects the text field to begin editing. If NO, the text field places an insertion point at the place where the user tapped the field.